# IntelliJ Subversion Authentication Required Dialog

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I am attempting to checkout a project from a subversion repository. I have entered in my information such as the url, username and password. I am able to see the list of folders in my repository. I select my project and select which directory to checkout to. Everything seems to be going great, I click OK to checkout in the Checkout Option, select 1.7 format (thats what I am using), push OK again the the hellish dialog that won't go away comes up. "Authentication Required". I fill in my username and password (which I KNOW is correct, I just used it earlier and saw all the folders in my repository to checkout). I click save credentials and click OK again. The dialog quickly goes away and pops up again as if I entered incorrect information. I have re-entered my information countless times now.

I click cancel finally and it says:

"Cannot checkout from svn: svn: E720002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://myurl.org/home/svn/project/projectname'
svn: E720002: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified."

I have two other people connecting to the repository and checking out the project the exact same way and it works fine. It used to work fine for me. The hard drive I had my checkout project to failed, gave me blue screen of death issues. I have since switched hard drives and this is the issue I am running into.

I have reinstalled both IntelliJ and svn. I have run it as administrator in Windows 7. I have deleted the Subverison cache stored in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Subversion to see if that would fix it. Still nothing seems to be working and I am out of ideas. I am using IntelliJ IDEA version 13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading to version 13.0.3, checking out my project from subversion, then upgrading to 13.1 fixed my issue. Intellij was not saving my subversion password. Not idea what the cause was.

Answer (score 13):

unchecking the "use command line client" (settings-->subversion-->general) solves this problem.

Comment: It did not work for me until I deleted old working repository from a disk that checked the sources out again and then unchecked custom SVN client.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a solution, but may help narrow down your issue:

Install the Subversion command line clint. You can get that from [SlikSVN](http://sliksvn.com/en/download/)<sup>1</sup>. You can also install the command line client when you install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoiseSVN.org). It's an **optional** package.

This way, we can determine if the problem is with Subversion or IntelliJ.

The `svn+ssh://` protocol is the trickiest to setup for a wide variety of reasons. It requires the repository to be hosted on a Unix like OS, and that all users who have access to the repository must be in the same Unix group, and that Unix group has read/write access to the repository, and the umask must be setup correctly too.

The best way to tell is to see if you can access the Subversion repository without going through IntelliJ.

---

<sup>1.</sup> There are many places to get the command line client for Subversion, but I find the SlikSVN site the easiest to find for Windows. CollabNet (which is what I use) requires registration, and then it takes a while to hunt down the non SubversionEdge install. Wandisco also has a client, but they push their SmartSVN package and bury the command line client on the bottom the page.

Comment: I already have TortoiseSVN with the command line optional package. I also am able to update my directory with the graphical interface of TortoiseSVN. Should I try updating with commandline? I have not done that. All users are in the same group on an ubuntu system.

Comment: You're able to access your repository with `svn+ssh://` over TortoiseSVN? That proves you have access to the repo from your system. The command line would be helpful if TortoiseSVN doesn't work because it'll give you a bit more information. However, Subversion access itself isn't the issue. This means that IntelliJ is the problem. Do you have SVNKit or JavaHL installed? I believe that IntelliJ's Subversion access is via these third party libraries.

Comment: I tend to use Eclipse. I'll have to download and install IntelliJ and see if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: I have not installed SVNKit or JavaHL. And yes I am able to use svn+ssh// via the GUI of tortoiseSVN

Comment: Do you think SVNKit or JavaHL libs that IntelliJ is using has separate caches I can clear out? I also thought maybe there is a log on the svn server I can see if IntelliJ is even attempting to make a connection on that auth dialog box.

Comment: If SVN was using httpd, you could check the access log. I don't know if sshd has a similar log setup. I don't think this is a cache issues. It could be an issue with public/private keys, but you're able to connect to the repo outside of IntelliJ.

Comment: I am not using key auth. I am using password only

Answer (score 2):

When I had this issue (on windows & Intellij 13) - deleting my *%APPDATA%/Subversion/auth* folder (in my case *C:\Users\YOUR_UID_HERE\AppData\Roaming\auth*) fixed the issue.  On unix or OSX you would find this (IIRC) in */etc/subversion/auth* or *~/.subversion/auth*

In my case the problem was in one specific file, so you could delete the *svn-simple* folder (or the folder corresponding to whatever authorization scheme you are using) within the auth folder if you want to opt for more of a scapel than a chain saw, or just the file within the scheme for the particular problematic realm that isn't remembering the credentials, but YMMV.  I typically work with just one realm per development VM, so zapping the whole auth folder worked for me with no side effects.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem.  The fix is really wired. I had to choose "svn v1.7" instead of "svn v1.8".  Everything works from there.

Comment: If anyone is using Intellij 2016.1.1, using 1.7 over 1.8 seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Choosing the "1.7.*" option in Intellij worked for me, using Intellij 2017.3.3 (U) , SVNKIT 1.8.8 and Fedora.

Answer (score -1):

> File>>Settings>>>Version Control>>subversion then select clear auth cache