# Can not authenticate with Subversion, InteliJ and SSH Agent

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, ssh, pageant

Hi I have a Suversion repository in which I want to connect with InteliJ. With TortoiseSVN I have no problems. But when I tried to connect with InteliJ there is a problem. Subversion version is 1.8.10. InteliJ version 14.0.3.

[image]

> Error:svn: E170012: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'svn+ssh://...............' svn: E170012: Can't create tunnel svn:
>   E720002: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

I have running **Pageant** with entered ppk key with pass phrase.

And more. I can revert from InteliJ but can not see history and can not commit.

Comment: Follow this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541218/intellij-subversion-authentication-required-dialog/27854434#27854434

Comment: unchecking the "use command line client" (settings-->subversion-->general)
I tried but the problem stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So. I in InteliJ I did:

[image]
[image]

Then I choose Subversion->Show History. User must be **svn**

[image]

*(if previous screen do not show execute in Idea Clear Authentication Cashe)*
 And I see history and see changes.

Comment: Note the double backslashes in SVN_SSH. It seems they are important.

Comment: Does not work with Android Studio. Svn keeps asking for username and password